# webpack 4, ignore-loader returning [object object], and how to ignore image paths even if they are broken?

Tags: webpack, sass

I am slowly updated a very old, and not well built site to use modern build tools.  I was previously using GulpJS to build it but we use Webpack for all of our newer things and I want to bring all of our build processes into parity with one another.

Anyway, one thing I do NOT want is for Webpack to handle our images or fonts that are referenced in my scss files (and JS files).  Things like file-loader will actually move the files to the root of the dist directory and rename them with some hash.  It's not the *worst* thing but I can guarantee that some people I work with are going to complain about it for reasons XYZ.  I am also using the copy plugin to just move the image folder over to dist which works fine for me.

I have tried to use the `ignore-loader` plugin but that seems to be transforming the image urls to `[object Object]`.  Further more, if the url is incorrect then Webpack will throw an error about not being able to resolve the path.

So for instance, in one of my scss files I have this css selector:

```
.box ul li {
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-image: url('img/list-grey-8px.gif') !important;
}
```

Now, that url path is broken and while I *could* fix it the scss files on this site have been neglected for a long time and there are likely countless broken paths like that.

So can I get Webpack to just flat out ignore these image and font paths?

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin'); // installed via npm
const distName = require('./package.json').name;
const glob = require('glob');
const paths = {
  root: './',
  srcRoot: './_src',
  distRoot: './dist',
  npmRoot: './node_modules',
  scssPath: './_src/scss',
  scssGlob: './_src/scss/**/*.scss',
};


const scssFiles = pattern => glob
  .sync(pattern)
  .reduce((entries, filename) => {
    const [, name] = filename.match(/([^/]+)\.scss$/)
    return { ...entries, [name]: filename }
  }, {})



module.exports = {
  entry: {
    [distName]: './_src/entry.js',
    [distName + '.min']: './_src/entry.js',
    'admin-tinymce': './_src/css/admin-tinymce.scss', 
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }],
      },
      // js
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          },
        },
      },
      // scss
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          // css
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
          // autoprefix things
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              sourceMap: true,
              plugins: [
                autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] }),
              ],
            },
          },
          // sass
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [
                '../',
                paths.npmRoot + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free',
                paths.srcRoot + '/scss',
                paths.npmRoot,
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // images
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'ignore-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].[hash].css',
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, paths.srcRoot + '/img'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, paths.distRoot + '/img'),
        copyUnmodified: true,
      },
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, paths.srcRoot + '/fonts'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, paths.distRoot + '/fonts'),
        copyUnmodified: true,
      },
    ]),
    new (webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin || webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin)(),
  ],
};
```

And the referenced `admin-tincymce.scss` file has this selector:

```
.box ul li {
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-image: url('img/list-grey-8px.gif') !important;
}
```

and the src folder looks like:

```
.
└── _src/
    ├── css/
    │   ├── admin-tincymce.scss
    │   └── some other scss files
    ├── img/
    │   ├── bullets
    │   ├── list-grey-8px.gif
    │   └── some other img folder
    └── js/
        └── entry.js
```

Comment: Try set css-loader `url` option.  it enables/disables url/image-set functions handling.

Answer (score 0):

Disable `url()` resolving.

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    url: false,
    sourceMap: true
  }
}
```